# How to send a Lambda function from commandline to a Haskell program?

Tags: haskell

What I would like to achieve:

```
./myHaskellProgram aLambdaFunc aFilePath
```

This `aLambdaFunc` is a string that the user provides and will run on the `aFilePath`.

I suppose I need `Template Haskell` and parse the `aLambdaFunc` string? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Template haskell (and quasi quoters) runs at compile time, not at runtime. You will need to work with some parser that transforms it into a function. You can make use of the ghc parser source code to define such parser.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Are there any existing examples?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16679089/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Wow that's really a hidden gem on Hackage! Super cool, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could just load your program into ghci and let the user type Haskell expressions.  And you can do a bit better using a custom quasi quoter.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a system call to invoke GHCI (very unsafe) or you could write an entire parser.

You have an example on the [ihaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/src/IHaskell/Eval/Parser.hs) project, which uses a parser to create an interactive kernel compatible with Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The [`mueval`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval) package attempts to sandbox and execute Haskell code at runtime. It seems to be what you're looking for. It is(was) used in production by Chris Done's [Try Haskell](https://github.com/tryhaskell/tryhaskell) and some parts of [lambdabot](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lambdabot-haskell-plugins).