# Using content of a string to call function with same name

Tags: haskell, eval

I have a main like the following:

```haskell
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  putStrLn $ functionName args
  where 
    functionName args = "problem" ++ (filter (/= '"') $ show (args!!0))
```

Instead of putting the name to stdout like I do it right now, I want to call the function.

I am aware of the fact, that I could use hint (as mentioned in [Haskell: how to evaluate a String like "1+2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582926/haskell-how-to-evaluate-a-string-like-12)) but I think that would be pretty overkill for just getting that simple function name.

At the current stage it does not matter if the program crashes if the function does not exist!

Comment: You can not lift a string into an executable expression in that manner.  The only ways are to interpret or compile the string, both of which would require you to specify imports to bring the desired functions (potential targets) into scope.

Comment: You mention hint, and a few folk have mentioned template Haskell, but anything other than you parsing the user input and selecting a function from your whitelist is a bit of a security issue; programs that allow the user to run arbitrary code aren't _easy_ to secure.

Comment: Yeah, that security aspect is the cause that made me choose an approch similar that @trolox suggested. In that datasructure I have now the function, its id and a title which I now also print out in main. So I don't have to have the function itself to be IO…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a string representation of an identifier, not without fancy non-standard features, because that information isn't retained after compilation. As such, you're going to have to write down those function names as string constants *somewhere*.

If the function definitions are all in one file anyway, what I would suggest is to use data types and lambdas to avoid having to duplicate those function names altogether:

```
Data Problem = {
    problemName :: String,
    evalProblem :: IO () # Or whatever your problem function signatures are
    }

problems = [Problem]
problems = [
    Problem {
        problemName = "problem1",
        evalProblem = do ... # Insert code here
        },
    Problem
        problemName = "problem2",
        evalProblem = do ... # Insert code here
        }
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case find (\x -> problemName x == (args!!0)) problems of
        Just x -> evalProblem x
        Nothing -> # Handle error
```

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I'd say the important takeaway here is that you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't trot out a TemplateHaskell solution!  Not always beginner friendly, but it could scrape the module and construct the `problems` variable automatically.

Comment: It's hard when you don't know *why* this problem needs solving. I hesitate to recommend a more robust solution when I have a feeling it's either a temporary measure or a poor design choice.

Answer (score 6):

Without taking special measures to preserve them, the names of functions will likely be gone completely in a compiled Haskell program.

I would suggest just making a big top-level map:

```
import Data.Map ( Map )
import qualified Data.Map as Map

functions :: Map String (IO ())
functions = Map.fromList [("problem1", problem1), ...]

call :: String -> IO ()
call name =
    case Map.lookup name of
        Nothing -> fail $ name + " not found"
        Just m -> m

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  call $ functionName args
  where 
    functionName args = "problem" ++ (filter (/= '"') $ show (args!!0))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to do this, you have a few approaches, but the easiest by far is to just pattern match on it

This method requires that all of your functions you want to call have the same type signature:

```
problem1 :: Int
problem1 = 1

problem2 :: Int
problem2 = 2

runFunc :: String -> Maybe Int
runFunc "problem1" = Just problem1
runFunc "problem2" = Just problem2
runFunc _ = Nothing

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn $ runFunc $ functionName args
```

This requires you to add a line to `runFunc` each time you add a new `problemN`, but that's pretty manageable.