# How to get the value returned by the 'eval' function?

Tags: haskell, eval

I'm new to functional programming and i'm having a hard time figuring out how to use the 'eval' function in Haskell. My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582926/haskell-how-to-evaluate-a-string-like-12/%22this%20question%22). I use the following code contained in the answer :

```
$ cabal install hint
...
$ ghci
> import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
> runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> eval "3 + 5"
Right "8"
```

It works fine and displays the result on my screen. My problem is that i don't know how to get this value as an Int, for example to store it in a variable. I would like to write a function that recives a String as a parameter. This String would be an arithmetic expression like "2+4-1" , and my function should return the result 5. I don't wanna go into grammar and stuff because i would like to compute expressions like "2^3+sin(log(4))" and it gets too complicated at this point. Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting a mathematical function evaluator or a program interpreter?  Using the Haskel interpreter to evaluate simple mathematical expressions is like using a sledgehammer to hang pictures.  The interpreter in Language.Haskell.Interpreter is designed for when you need to execute arbitrary Haskell code, but a simple numeric expression evaluator is much more limited in scope and won't have to live in the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 4):

You should read my comment on the question you linked:

> Obviously you can read the haddock documents yourself, but really quickly the interpret function will give you a result of polymorphic type (not a string representation), which might be even better depending on your needs. Happy hacking.

In otherwords, just use the `interpret` function:

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.Interpreter> runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] \
                    >> interpret "3+5" (undefined :: Int)
Right 8
```

What is that `(undefined :: Int)`?  It is a type witness that allows the function `interpret` to reason about the result type.