# String to variable name Haskell

Tags: parsing, variables, haskell, eval, parsec

I find it hard to learn Parsec in Haskell so I'm trying to make my college project( a parser that parses files with the form

```
x=3
y=4
z=x+y
badluck=(x+sqrt(z)*7)
```

I managed to write a function that gets everything from the file and validates the file and I am stuck at making x be the variable name. I know in javascript it's eval but I can't find anything similar in Haskell.
Please help!

This is what I have done until now:

```
ischarorscore :: Char -> Bool
ischarorscore a = if ((a>='A' && a<='Z') || (a>='a' && a<='z') || a=='_')
        then True 
        else False

ischarscoredigit :: Char -> Bool
ischarscoredigit a = if ((a>='A' && a<='Z') || 
                      (a>='a' && a<='z') || 
                       a=='_' ||
                       a>='0' && a<='9') then True else False

isvar :: String -> Bool
isvar [] = False
isvar (h:t) = if (ischarorscore h) then (isvarbody t) else False

isvarbody :: String -> Bool
isvarbody [] = True
isvarbody (h:t) = if (ischarscoredigit h) then (isvarbody t) else False

isoperator :: Char -> Bool
isoperator a = if (a=='+' || a=='-' || a=='*' || a=='/' || a=='^') then True else False

issqrt :: String -> Bool
issqrt [] = True
issqrt x = if (x=="sqrt(") then True else False

isnumber :: String -> Bool
isnumber (h:t) = if (h>='0' && h<='9') then isnumber t else False

charsetall :: String -> Bool
charsetall [] = True
charsetall (h:t) = if (h>='0' && h<='9' ||
                h>='a' && h<='z' ||
                h>='A' && h<='Z' ||
                h>='0' && h<='9' ||
                h=='+' || h=='-' || h=='*' || h=='/' || h=='^' ||           h=='(' || h==')' || h=='=')
                then charsetall t else False

charsetexpr :: String -> Bool
charsetexpr [] = True
charsetexpr (h:t) = if (h>='0' && h<='9' ||
                h>='a' && h<='z' ||
                h>='A' && h<='Z' ||
                h>='0' && h<='9' ||
                h=='+' || h=='-' || h=='*' || h=='/' || h=='^' || h=='(' || h==')')
                then charsetexpr t else False

paranthesis :: String -> Int -> Bool
paranthesis [] a = if (a==0) then True else False
paranthesis (h:t) a = if (h=='(') then (paranthesis t (a+1)) 
                    else (if (h==')') then
                      paranthesis t (a-1) else paranthesis t a)

paranthesis' :: String -> Bool
paranthesis' (h:t) = paranthesis (h:t) 0

obeyrules :: String -> Bool
obeyrules [] = True
obeyrules (h:t) = if (ischarorscore h) then (contvar t) 
              else if (h>='0' && h<='9') then (contnumber t)
              else if (h=='(' || h=='-') then obeyrules t
              else False

contnumber :: String -> Bool
contnumber [] = True
contnumber (h:t) = if (h>='0' && h<='9') then contnumber t
            else if (isoperator h) then contoperator t
            else if (h==')') then contoperator h
            else False

contvar :: String -> Bool
contvar [] = True
contvar (h:t) = if (ischarorscore h || h>='0' && h<='9') then contvar t
            else if (isoperator h) then contoperator t
            else if (h==')') then contoperator
            else False

contoperator :: String -> Bool
contoperator [] = True
contoperator (h:t) = if (ischarorscore h) then contvar t
                else if (h>='0' && h<='9') then contnumber t
                else if (h=='(') then obeyrules t
                else False


isexpression :: String -> Bool
isexpression [] = True
isexpression (h:t) = if (charsetexpr (h:t) && paranthesis' (h:t) && obeyrules (h:t)) then True else False
```

The isexpression function combines all the functions above to validate a line of the file. The project is like this : you have to read a random file that looks like the one above and contains variable name = expression and recognises (,),+,-,*,/,^ which is power, sqrt(k) where k is number or variable name, and mod, calculate the expressions and provide the resulting variable names and their values.

Comment: Unclear question. Can you rephrase what exactly you have done (code, perhaps?) and what exactly you want to achieve (example pairs of input and output)?

Comment: @larsmans `ghci` called :) (to tell you about [`System.Eval.Haskell`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-1.5.1.4/docs/System-Eval-Haskell.html) )

Comment: You might be looking for an interpreter, it is unclear.  Consider using hint, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582926/haskell-how-to-evaluate-a-string-like-12/5584638#5584638

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely want to parse what's called an Abstract Syntax Tree. For the fragment given here, it might look like

```
data AST
  = Var String
  | Lit Double
  | Plus AST AST
  | Mult AST AST
  | Sqrt AST
  | Assign String AST
  | Then AST AST
```

With this choice of AST, the fragment of code you have given looks like

```
fragment :: AST
fragment = foldr1 Then [
    Assign "x" (Lit 3)
  , Assign "y" (Lit 4)
  , Assign "z" (Plus (Var "x") (Var "y"))
  , Assign "badluck" (Plus (Var "x") (Mult (Sqrt (Var "z")) (Lit 7)))
  ]
```

We then pick an evaluator function which converts these AST values to their "canonical" values. In this case, the basic canonical value would be a `Double`, but since the AST could fail due to referring to an unknown variable, we'll have the canonical value be `Maybe Double` instead. Finally, since we expect the environment to change as expressions are evaluated, we return the updated environment.

In order to operationalize this evaluator, we need a notion of the environment which gets assigned to. A good choice for this is `Data.Map`

```
import           Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Map            as Map
import           Data.Map            (Map)

type Env = Map String Double

eval :: Env -> AST -> Maybe (Double, Env)
eval env (Var s) = fmap (\x -> (x, env)) (Map.lookup s env)
eval env (Plus e1 e2) = do -- maybe monad
  (v1, env')  <- eval env  e1
  (v2, env'') <- eval env' e2
  return (v1 + v2, env'')
eval env (Mult e1 e2) = do -- maybe monad
  (v1, env')  <- eval env  e1
  (v2, env'') <- eval env' e2
  return (v1 * v2, env'')
eval env (Sqrt e)     = fmap (\(x, e) -> (sqrt x, e)) (eval env e)
eval env (Assign s e) = do
  (v, env') <- eval env e
  return (v, Map.insert s v env')
eval env (Then e1 e2) = do 
  (_, env')  <- eval env  e1
  (v, env'') <- eval env' e2
  return (v, env'')
```

Technically, this could have been done using a monad transformer stack of `State Env` and `Maybe`, but as written the operation might be a little more clear if tedious.

Comment: This is great, but I don't understand too much of the code. I have read Parsec documentation and Real World Haskell chapter 16 and still can't wrap my head around it. This code is not Parsec but still trying to understand hurts. Also I have updated the question

Comment: Parsec is a way of building a function like `parse :: String -> AST`. That's the first step. Then you evaluate the AST with something like `eval Map.empty :: AST -> Maybe (Double, Env)`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `Data.Map`? There are no "variables" in Haskell, so it would serve you better and would be much easier to use.

---

To elaborate a bit: once you read a variable identifier from a file with your desired intialization syntax, like so:

```
<<name>> = <<value>>
```

insert a new entry into your `Map`, which would just be a `(name, value)` pair. Names would be rather obviously of type `String`, and floating point types should be OK for the value type (if you're dealing with numbers only). Every time a variable assignment depends on another variable, just `lookup` it and use the value. To hold the changing map of values, you can simply use `State`.