# Haskell convert string to integer list

Tags: string, haskell, integer

I have the following string `[1..5]` and I want to convert it to the Integer list [1,2,3,4,5]. I tried doing this using read but that does not work. Is there any simple trick to convert such a list to an Integer list or will it require a parser?

Comment: Why don't you use a language with built-in eval, like Ruby or Python? This is totally not a task Haskell was ever intended to do.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you will need an interpreter to do so. You might want to do something along the line of:

```
$ cabal install hint
...
$ ghci
> import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
> runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> eval "[1..5]"
```

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584638/55070