# How to run a Haskell code by its name?

Tags: haskell, reflection

First of all, I'm new in Haskell and I'm curious how can I implement something that I have working in Java.

**A bit of prehistory:**

I have a Java-based project with workers. Workers can be started periodically and do some work. A worker - is just a Java-class with some functionality implemented. New workers can be added and configured. Workers' names and parameters are stored in a data base. Periodically, the application gathers workers' details (names, params) from DB and starts them. In Java, to start worker by its name, I do the following:

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("com.mycompany.superworker");
Constructor<?> constructor = myClass.getConstructor();
MyClass myInstance = (MyClass) constructor.newInstance();
myInstance.run("param1", "param2");
```

Hence, the application gets worker's name (the actual class name) from DB, gets class and constructor, creates new instance of the class and then just runs it.

**Now, the question:** how I could implement something similar in Haskell? I mean, if I have some function/module/class whatever implemented in Haskell and I have its name stored in plain text, - then how can I run this code by its name (from the main Haskell-based application, of course)?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

A bit more about the app...
I have an application that grabs some data from Internet, does some parsing work and puts the result in DB. We have a vary of websites we grab data from, so we have a vary of parsers. These parsers are workers. User can implement its own worker (a java class) and put its details into DB via UI. So we store names of workers (and their params) in DB. And when it's time, we go to DB, gather workers' class names and instantiate and start every worker.

Workers do not need communication between each other. Application also don't need to communicate to workers. Application just start a worker, worker grabs data from web, does some parsing, and puts result into DB. That's it.

So, worker can be launched as a separate process.

The main problem (as for me) is that we don't have some constant amount of workers. User can implement its own worker, compile it, restart the application, and the application should know how to start this new worker. So, we store workers' class names in DB and use Java reflection to launch them.

I'm looking for how such an app could be written in Haskell - in a Haskell way, not necessary to just copy the existing Java way.

Comment: Perhaps you should give this concept its proper name: reflection. I will tag the question.

Comment: This particular brand of reflection is not a service that the Haskell language provides, though it's pretty straightforward to build (something like) it yourself. What exactly are you hoping to achieve? I suspect this is an X/Y problem, so if you could clarify the underlying problem you're trying to solve we could probably provide some alternatives.

Comment: If your _really_, _really_ must: [plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins) -- Dynamic linking and runtime evaluation of Haskell, and C, including dependency chasing and package resolution. Using this when not necessary may be considered very bad style.

Comment: Your example does not show any communication between the workers and the application code that launches them, nor any in-JVM communication between the workers. I don't know if that's an artifact of the example or a fact about your system, but I think it points to a key question: do the workers really need to be in the same process as the one that launches them? If not, a simple solution is just for the coordinator to launch them as processes. This approach is also known in the Java world—for example, Hadoop normally launches "workers" as separate processes.

Comment: As an easy to use alternative to plugins, I suggest looking at hint. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582926/haskell-how-to-evaluate-a-string-like-12/5584638#5584638)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson say, I have an application that grabs some data from Internet, does some parsing work and puts the result in DB. We have a vary of websites we grab data from, so we have a vary of parsers. These parsers are workers. User can implement its own worker (a java class) and put its details into DB via UI. So we store names of workers (and their params) in DB. And when it's time, we go to DB, gather workers' class names and instantiate and start every worker. I'm looking on how such an app could be written in Haskell - in a Haskell way, not necessary to copy the existing Java way.

Comment: @chi I'm not sure if I really must to do that. I'm actually looking how I could rewrite such an app in Haskell. And I have some part of it that uses Java reflection. So I need to find an Haskell analog of this feature, or rewrite this part in a Haskell way.

Comment: @LuisCasillas no communication between workers. No communication between a worker and the app. I think, worker not necessarily should be in the same process as the one launched it. Let's say, it doesn't mater. OK, but how could I launch a process in Haskell if I know just a function name (storing in as a text in DB) or a class name or so?

Comment: @fych: you can just compile each worker to a different executable and launch them by name.